# How can I pass a parameter value from PHP to jasper report query?

Tags: php, jasper-reports, parameter-passing

I want to pass student number `'2014000030'` as parameter value so that i only get the report for that student. How do i do that using the sql query below the code. The below code is how i have done it, but its not working, where did I go it wrong?

**PHP code**

```
<?php
 //Import the PhpJasperLibrary
include_once('PhpJasperLibrary/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
include_once("PhpJasperLibrary/PHPJasperXML.inc.php");

//database connection details

$server="localhost";
$db="student_portal";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$version="0.8b";
$pgport=5432;
$pchartfolder="./class/pchart2";

$value = '2014000030';

//display errors should be off in the php.ini file
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

//setting the path to the created jrxml file
$xml =  simplexml_load_file("test.jrxml");

$PHPJasperXML = new PHPJasperXML();
//$PHPJasperXML->debugsql=true;
$PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter=array("parameter1"=>$value);
$PHPJasperXML->xml_dismantle($xml);
$PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray($server,$user,$pass,$db);
$PHPJasperXML->outpage("I");    //page output method I:standard output  D:Download file
?>
```

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT i.stid,i.surname,i.first_name,i.other_names,i.dob,i.course,b.branch_name,r.exam_no,r.modules,m.module_name,r.result,rr.remark FROM modules m,info i,results r,branches b,result_remarks rr WHERE r.modules=m.module_code AND i.campus_code=b.branch_code AND i.stid=r.stid AND rr.result=r.remark
```

Comment: Eventually this is what should be i.stid='2014000030', but i don't how to pass the value from PHP to the report. Please help the guy out. Thanx

Comment: it's an integer type in a database table. Im not sure if you got my question right. i want to pass the student number 2014000030 from PHP code to jaspereport, so that i only get a report for this particular student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this command

```
$PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter=array("parameter1"=>$value);
```

You are passing the value to jasperReport as an parameter with the parameter name  `"parameter1"`

**Define the parameter** inside of your `jrxml` (use the class corresponding to your database)

```
<parameter name="parameter1" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

Then **use it in query** (`i.stid=$P{parameter1}`).

```
SELECT i.stid,i.surname,i.first_name,i.other_names,i.dob,i.course,b.branch_name,r.exam_no,r.modules,m.module_name,r.result,rr.remark 
FROM modules m,info i,results r,branches b,result_remarks rr 
WHERE i.stid=$P{parameter1} AND r.modules=m.module_code AND i.campus_code=b.branch_code AND i.stid=r.stid AND rr.result=r.remark
```

Its important to set correct class (same as database column) of `$P{parameter1}` and pass same class as parameter, since jasper report will use **prepared statement** when query is executed.

**Note:** you can use query expression `i.stid='$P!{parameter1}'` and jasper report will do string substitution, but this is not recommend since your code will allow sql injection.

Comment: Thank you for your response. From which section/part do i define the parameter inside my jxml.

Comment: Before your fields see http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd, or use IDE and click add parameter...

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it and it is now working. Now i understand how to use the parameters. I used the one from the IDE. I also opened the xml to see where it has placed the definition of a parameter.

Comment: @MoloraneMothusi If it works, consider to accept the answer (green check next to the answer)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same question last days too. I am using the same library for displaying Reports nicely in PHP based on reports generated in iReports. The question for me was: I needed to use some filters to refine the Report according to my needs. Usually, parameters I have used are dynamically according to the data from DB.

My approach is totally not inline with Documentation but it is more easy and applicable. I hope my approach will help someone else who would look for similar solution like mine too ;) It is  not needed to add additional Parameters in report to refine report, it is simple just to overwrite the SQL parsed by PHP adding new parameters directly in SQL...
Just a simple as my bellow example:

```
$customer = $_GET['ID'];
$xml =  simplexml_load_file("reports/customers.jrxml");

$PHPJasperXML = new PHPJasperXML();
$PHPJasperXML->xml_dismantle($xml);
$PHPJasperXML->sql ="SELECT ID, NAME, ADDRESS, IMAGE FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ID = '$customer'";
$PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray($server,$user,$pass,$db);
$PHPJasperXML->outpage("I");
```